# Using Apache POI SXSSF API to write xlsx using a template with built in formatting

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to see if it's possible to let a template handle the formatting (ex: converting strings (numbers, dates, decimal values) to their native data types) when writing data to xlsx using POI SXSSF API rather than having the application use the appropriate setCellValue(Date/int/String/double) methods when writing data.

I tested out this scenario as mentioned below, but it doesn't seem to be working. I would appreciate any suggestions here.

1. Created a .xlsx template with a header row containing the cells an_integer, a_decimal_number, a_date and a_string. I formatted each column in the header to the appropriate type by right clicking the column and selecting 'Format Cells'.
2. Used the SXSSF API and added the row containing the data 121, 132.7612, 03/13/2013, I am a string, and using the setCellValue(String) method for all the cells.
   I was expecting the data to be automatically converted to their respective types as the columns were formatted to do so. However, this doesn't seem to be happening, and the generated excel file still treats the numbers and date as strings.

Was my template of the wrong format ? Is what I was trying to do feasible at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `setCellValue(String)` in [`XSSFCell`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html) will automatically set the cell type of the cell to `CELL_TYPE_STRING`, overwriting whatever previous cell type was there, thus changing how Excel formats the cell value.

Try using one of the overloaded `setCellValue` methods; each of them set the cell type according to the type of its argument:

- setCellValue(boolean) - `CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN`
- setCellValue(Calendar) - `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` (Excel stores its dates as numbers)
- setCellValue(Date) - `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` (Excel stores its dates as numbers)
- setCellValue(double) - `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`
- setCellValue(RichTextString) - `CELL_TYPE_STRING`
- setCellValue(String) - `CELL_TYPE_STRING`

Comment: rgettman@ - Thanks for the reply. I am trying to see if there's a way to let the template handle the formatting (string -> date, string -> integer etc. conversions) rather than the application having to call the appropriate overridden methods based on the data it writes. Is it possible for templates to do this ?

Comment: No, Apache POI assumes that the caller knows which datatype it's supposed to be.  You could provide an facade API on top of POI that switches based on the contents of the template cell, e.g. "a_decimal_number" means call `Double.parseDouble` on the user input and then call `setCellValue(double)`.